# IPTABLES doesn't store the ip address entered inside the rule

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm working on a debian server and when i add the following rules to forward a port to a lan address:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 3385 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.9:3389

iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d 192.168.1.2/10 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

i get the following with iptables -L:

```
    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.128.0.0/10      state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

the LAN ip address of the debian server is 192.168.1.1 and it is connected to the internet and to the local network over one only interface and all the local network computers have an ip from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.10.
I'm using an exact clone of this debian server on another location and i don't have this problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: by mistake, i didn't enabled iptables rules to be loaded at startup and had to re-add iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're giving us matches with the input you've given us. There is no issue here. The only thing different is that the bits that are irrelevant due to the mask you chose are not output by `iptables`, so you see `192.128.0.0/10` rather than `192.168.1.2/10`.

If that's a mistake, adjust the mask so that it is the correct value (probably `/24`) and it should work.

Comment: you're right, i forgot to set iptables rules to be loaded at startup and had to re-add the rule iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE then it worked as expected.